# how to get GPS coordinates polygon

Tags: gps, coordinates, polygon

Let's say, I want to get coordinates of polygon points for Arizona state. I manually right click the boundary lines of AZ in Google map to get the coordinates. Is there any way to get the polygon coordinates  by state or city ? Thanks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download them from OpenStreetMap.
But be prepared, some countries like United Kingdom have more than 50.000 polygon points.

Further think what is your desired accuracy?
800m or as best as it could be?

For rough like 800m there is another source, too. In Esri Shp file format, free.
But i have forgotten where.

Comment: You may find the following tutorial helpful: it walks you through the process of downloading the data and using it http://www.spatialanalysis.ca/2011/using-openstreetmap-data-part1/

Comment: I would like to have as accurate as possible since I am trying to add all gps polygon points in U.S. Thank you